# How to decide if inequality is in the range or seperate?

Tags: inequality

when solving an inequality, for example $x^2 + x - 2 > 0$, when I get the solutions, how do I know if to write 1 < x < -2, or 1 < x, x < -2 as separately? This is confusing me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually simultaneous inequalities $$a < x < b$$
are short for $a < x$, **and** $x< b$. But then, such an $x$ can only exist if $a< b$.

Clearly what you want is $1<x$, **or** $x < -2$, so this is the correct way. Even the comma seperated statements sometimes stand for **and**, so I would go with an explicit **or** statement.

In any case never should you write something like $$1< x < -2$$
unless you really mean to note that $x$ doesn't exist.

Comment: When do I know which one to use? Some of my answers in my worksheet say a < x < b, some say x > c, x < d.

Comment: @user164403 What you need to be sure of is whether you want to write an *and* statement (both inequalities satisfied at once), or an *or* statement (either inequality satisfied, one at a time). The rest is just scripture: $\cdot < \cdot < \cdot$ for *and*, $ \cdot < \cdot\, ,\quad \cdot<\cdot$ for *or* (I assume your worksheets use the last convention, but *I* would write *or* instead of a comma).